# The best cache framework for caching in mybatis

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, mybatis, ehcache

At this moment, I am using default cache system of `mybatis`.
I mean simple: `<cache/>` in mapper files.

However, I noted that there is variety of different cache provided out of the box for mybatis.

`Can you tell me if it is good idea to change default mybatis to`memcached`or`ehcache` ? Or maybe there exists another 
**out of the box** framework for mybatis ?

To be more precisely, I think what can I benefit? Improving efficiency ?

My additional requirement (which is not satisfied by my default mybatis cache) is:

In mapper I have (it is simpler situation than in reality, but it give a well intuition).

```
<mapper>
    <cache/>
    <select>
        SELECT * FROM myFun(#{name})
        <!-- it is cached -->
    </select>


    <insert> <!-- it flushes cache (*) -->
        INSERT INTO ...

        VALUES
        <foreach item="iter">
            (#{name}, #{iter})
        </foreach>
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

I understand why it flush cache. However, 
is it possible to flush this cache only in case of repeating parameter `name` ?
Let's assume that we cached results for select with `name=John`, 
then let someone insert value with `name=Tom`. Now, cache will be flushed,
I would like to flush only queries cached for `SELECT * FROM myFun('Tom')` query.